# How do I remove any protrusions from a smooth object?

Tags: objects

[image]I want to flatten and smoothen the spots shown by the blue arrows so the shark looks more realistic.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing how the geometry is arranged on those areas. Can you add an image in edit mode?

Comment: @cegaton Yes, I will be able to at 5:00 after school. Would you be able to check it out then?

Comment: @cegaton   I just posted my shark in edit mode. Take a look when you have a chance

Comment: The problem you are seeing might have to do with having a bunch of extra faces along the far edge of that shark. https://i.imgur.com/NfOzChH.png The quickest way to fix this would be to select the whole mesh in edit mode and W > Remove Doubles. It looks like the faces in those areas were extruded at one point, but not actually moved.

Comment: if you switch to vertex select, clear the selection and hit ctrl-shift-alt-m, you might see the problems lighting up.